# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, gmail

Some months ago, I used gmail setting in my .env file,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myEmail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=myPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

It was working perfectly fine. But suddenly it stopped working. 
Now, it is showing an error, which is:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING) proc_open() has been disabled for security reasons
```

What's going on?? I have tried all the methods found on internet but didn't worked.
Did Gmail got any new security system?

I have tried changing,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail to MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

But getting below error,

```
Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]
```

Comment: What's the PHP version? Looks like [a known bug](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/544) with PHP 5.6

Comment: I'm using php 7.2

Comment: Can anyone help me??